# Elegant way of changing a variable in Ruby if it equals a specific value

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a more elegant way to do this:

```
my_var = nil if my_var == 2
```

Currently I have to repeat `my_var` twice which doesn't read or look very nice.

This becomes even more ugly if I `my_var` is a key from a hash:

```
my_hash[:my_key] = nil if my_hash[:my_key] == 12
```

If I wanted to change it only if it was already nil then I could do this:

```
my_var ||= 2
```

Which is much cleaner.

Is there any nicer way of changing a variables value if it is equal to a certain value?

Comment: I can understand your concern. I think most would agree that `my_var = nil if my_var == 2` is almost as ugly as a field of tulips in bloom. The values of variables can only be changed via assignment, so to achieve the desired result without repeating `my_var` one needs to write either `if xxxx; my_var = nil; end` or `my_var = yyyy`, where the expressions `xxxx` and `yyyy` do not reference `my_var`, which cannot be. If it can be done using *abbreviated assignment* (`x  o= ...`, where `o=` is a placeholder for `+=`, `|=` and so on), and I don't think...

Comment: ...it can (but proving that is another matter), I doubt very much if the result would be less ugly than that which it is replacing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use sentinel values to represent `nil` values.

Here's one way, which may or may not exactly fit your situation. First, define a function that generates your nilifier, based on your chosen sentinel value:

```
def make_nilifier sentinel
  -> (var) { var == sentinel ? nil : var }
end
```

In your first example, the sentinel values is 2:

```
nilifier = make_nilifier 2
```

Then, you can assign values to `my_var` via calls to the `nilifier`:

```
> my_var = nilifier.call 1
> my_var
=> 1

> my_var = nilifier.call 2
> my_var
=> nil
```

In your case, you are checking values that are already set - this provides a way to check the value on assignment. Again, it may or may not exactly fit, but may give some ideas toward something useful.